# Paperclip validates_attachment_content_type for mp3 triggered when attaching mp3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mp3, paperclip

Struggling to workout when i add the following validtion to my Voice model using paperclip, it is being triggered when i try and upload an mp3:

```
class Voice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :clip

  validates_attachment_presence :clip
  validates_attachment_content_type :clip, :content_type => [ 'application/mp3', 'application/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/mp3' ],
                                    :message => 'file must be of filetype .mp3'

  validates_attachment_size :clip, :less_than => 10.megabytes                                    

  validates_presence_of :title      
end
```

I have tried a number of different mp3 files but none of them seem to upload because the validation is failing.

Answer (score 5):

Wrong content type? Try audio/mpeg.

http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp

Comment: Well the array of content types i went with initially to allow was:

[ 'application/mp3', 'application/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/mp3' ],

However the content type getting saved to the database was 'audio/mpg' which i thought was odd. So is there something dodgy about my mp3's or something else weird going on? This does seem odd.

Answer (score 4):

Just being silly, sorry.

I simply removed the validation, viewed in the db what the content_type was being saved as ('audio/mpg') and added it to the aray of allowed content_types in the validation.

Job done :-)

Comment: Hello. I am trying for audio/wav type. But it doesn't work. Could you please help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

For an (hopefully) complete mp3-support I used the following mimetypes:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :audio,
  :content_type => [ 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but If a user has other browser (or other version of browser) mp3's content type could be interpreted in unexpected way and he will not have the ability to save mp3.

Comment: I agree, i think it's going to be a case of building up an array of content_types that are all valid for an mp3 to cover all bases.

Answer (score 0):

So, oddly enough, I was having this problem tonight, and none of the above solutions were working for me. I was getting this error:

```
`[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename blah_blah_blah.mp3 (audio/mp3 from Headers, ["audio/mpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: application/octet-stream. See documentation to allow this combination.`
```

I solved it by using this as my validator:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :recording,
content_type: [
  'application/mp3',
  'application/x-mp3',
  'audio/mpeg',
  ['audio/mpeg'], # note the array around the type
  'audio/mp3'
],
message: 'File must be of filetype .mp3'
```

Hopefully this helps someone.